# How to set a server side parameter on an a entity data source

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a gridview which I databind to EntityModel

This typically looks like

something a
something b
companyID

on Login I get and set the compnay which has the ID so what in essence I want to do is on databind set the Where clause of data source to what the server side paramter for company ID is.

I am sure this is super simple but it is driving me nuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [WhereParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.whereparameters.aspx) of EntityDataSource? In declarative approach you can use any type of predefined parameters or define your own parameter derived from [Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.aspx). WhereParameters are also accessible from code behind and I think you should be able to modify collection in OnSelecting event handler.